# What will happen to the return type of assignment operator if it is not taken while calling?

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, return-value-optimization

I was working on operator overloading of `=` and saw the below example.

```
class Ratio {
    public:
        Ratio(int , int  );
        Ratio(const Ratio&);
        Ratio& operator= (const Ratio&);
    private:
        int nNum, nDenum;
};

Ratio::Ratio(int n = 0, int d = 1) {
    nNum = n;
    nDenum = d;
}

Ratio::Ratio(const Ratio &T) {
    nNum = T.nNum;
    nDenum = T.nDenum;
}

Ratio& Ratio::operator= (const Ratio& R) {
    nNum = R.nNum;
    nDenum = R.nDenum;
    return *this;
}

int main() {
    Ratio r1;
    Ratio r2(2,3);
    r1 = r2;//STATEMENT 1
}
```

This code is working well but I want to know why? As the function `operator=` is returning a reference to a Ratio object but in STATEMENT 1 we are not taking the return reference in any Ratio object.

Comment: Why do you think it matters?

Answer (score 5):

Nothing happens. `operator=` returning a reference is just for the usage to chain them together. Such as:

```
r1 = r2 = r3;
```

And assignment is right-associative, so the above assignment chain is parsed like this:

```
r1 = (r2 = r3);
```

Anyway, this is just a convention, but is followed by all the built-in types as well as by all the types in the standard library.

Comment: I completely understand that it is done just to make an analogy with the default = operator functionality but the  syntax of the function is stating that it would return a reference and we are not abiding the the given prototype which we should while calling as we can call it like
r1 = r2
In this we are not taking the return reference.. Please let me know if I am wrong in the above statement.

Comment: @Learner I'm not sure if I caught your doubt correctly, `operator=` returning a reference is just for the other convenient usage, in the case `r1 = r2`, the returned reference is just not used, and discarded.